# validate a numeric column postgres

Tags: postgresql

im trying to validate a column using postgresql
where values in the column are (0000-ASZAS)  four numerical values-five alphbets

```
SELECT invoice_number,
CASE
WHEN invoice_number = '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' 
THEN 'valid'
ELSE 'invalid'
END
from invoices;
```

also tried LIKE instead of =

sorry wrong column customer_id with alpha numeric values
invoice_number is numeric. thank you for the correction

Comment: This question makes no sense. a "numeric" column cannot contain [A-Z] to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ~ or similar_to. See [functions-matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

```
WHEN invoice_number ~ '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

Comment: ~ gives me an error: operator does not exist: numeric ~ unknown

Comment: What version of postgres?

Comment: PostgreSQL 14..

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/_j5chXE2

Comment: working now as much as i want to vote i still need points thank you everyone :)

Comment: Note that this pattern would also match e.g. `0000-ASZAS-1234`.

Comment: Yes, I just copied the pattern from the OP

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `~` POSIX regex operator:

```sql
SELECT invoice_number,
       CASE WHEN invoice_number ~ '^[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{5}$' 
            THEN 'valid'
            ELSE 'invalid' END
FROM invoices;
```

Comment: for some reason it wont accept LIKE or ~ If i use = i get ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "^[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{5}$"

Comment: The error message almost sounds like `invoice_number` is numeric.  Check your table data.  By the way, put _single_ quotes around the regex on the RHS.

Comment: it is, my bad. I used the wrong column i could use this for the invoice column. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm cleaning a data and want to return 0 rows so it doesn't crowd the results so this is what I did...

```
SELECT customer_id FROM invoices
WHERE customer_id !~ '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]';
```

w/c gives me exactly what I want. Would this be as strong/valid for cleaning compared to using like or = ?